# Is the official MATLAB computer vision toolbox actually OpenCV?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I can't help but notice that the MATLAB documentation for the Computer Vision toolbox has a very familiar feel, as if it is a re-write of the OpenCV docs and examples.

This is the MATLAB toolbox doc:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/computer-vision/

This is the opencv doc:
http://docs.opencv.org/

Now I currently don't have MATLAB so I can't really check.  Does anyone know if it is actually MEX OpenCV?

Cheers

Comment: Also see this link: http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-opencv.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MATLAB for the most part uses OpenCV libraries underneath the hood for their CV toolbox.  However, I would like to note that the Computer Vision Toolbox also implements some functionality that is independent of the OpenCV libraries but a good majority of what the toolbox provides uses OpenCV functionality.  As quoted by Amro in his comment below:

> *Like many other areas, MATLAB wraps well-known libraries in an easy to use format (think BLAS/LAPACK, FFTW, SparseSuite, just to name a few!). So while MATLAB does make use of OpenCV in its CVST toolbox, it adds many other algorithms not found in OpenCV (either implemented in M-code or a lower-level language).*

In addition, you are certainly able to interface OpenCV code with MATLAB if you have code already written in this platform and would like to interface that with MATLAB if you are developing MATLAB products and want to take full advantage of OpenCV.  See this link for more details (courtesy of Amro): http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-opencv.html

Some of the MEX functions that called in the Computer Vision toolbox that ultimately get run call OpenCV C++ methods in the end.  Inside the folder of where MATLAB is installed, if you actually take a look at the `bin/os/` folder where `os` is the operating system you're using (for me, it's `maci64`), you'll see a `libopencv` folder.  In this folder, you will see a lot of dynamically linked libraries that are basically those from OpenCV to which the MATLAB MEX functions that are part of the CV toolbox access in the end.

To navigate here in MATLAB, type this into the MATLAB command prompt:

```
>> cd (matlabroot)/bin/
```

.. then go into the folder that is for your operating system, then finally go to the `libopencv` folder.

You will also see what version of OpenCV is being used when calling the functions in the OpenCV library and the version number is appended at the end of each of the files. As such, if you want to use OpenCV for any of your MEX functions, perhaps the easiest thing would be to use the version that is pre-loaded into MATLAB to escape any compilation / setup headaches. With this, make sure you access the appropriate documentation for this version of OpenCV.

As such, for those functions in the toolbox that do use OpenCV, it's really a three step process:

1. The Computer Vision Toolbox provides MATLAB wrappers for you to call your functions.
2. Inside these MATLAB wrappers, there may be some pre-processing steps which then get passed to a MEX function.  There may be functions in the CV toolbox in MATLAB where you're just calling a MEX function directly and the MATLAB wrapper may just include the doc string of what function you are calling.
3. Inside the MEX code, they are calling OpenCV functions from the OpenCV libraries which then spit out the results you need.  Now, I'm not quite sure **which** MATLAB CV functions are calling OpenCV functions themselves, but I do know that a good majority of the MATLAB CV toolbox does call OpenCV under the hood.

Comment: wow! Didn't know all these useful info. Wonder if this is true with other OSs too! +1

Comment: @Divakar - ahaha thanks :) I found this out by accident when I was trying to install OpenCV MATLAB wrappers written by Kota Yamaguchi so that I could actually use the OpenCV libraries directly in MATLAB: http://vision.is.tohoku.ac.jp/~kyamagu/software/mexopencv/. I had to do a lot of hacking and doctoring of files, which included changing some of the dynamically linked libraries found in the `libopencv` folder. When I saw that, and I opened up some of the MEX files that MATLAB calls in their CV toolbox, I discovered that there were OpenCV calls in their files.  It was found by accident really!

Comment: @Divakar - Part #2 - As of the end of last year, OpenCV created a MATLAB branch on Github that allows the creation of MATLAB wrappers and their associated compiled files so that you can use OpenCV directly in MATLAB.  In essence, this puts the work by Kota Yamaguchi to be out of play, but I used his libraries before OpenCV decided to create a MATLAB branch.  Check: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv .  The advantage of this is that you have access to **all** of the methods the library has to offer, while MATLAB only uses a subset of the full OpenCV library.

Comment: Bookmarked those links, kool stuffs! Thank you on those! If only this opencv under-the-hood-play could be ascertained on other OSs too, could be very useful for many users as not everyone is lucky enough to have MAC :) On the part#2, MATLAB did the same with GPU too, well that's a long but similar story.

Comment: In fact, on second thought I copied your very useful comments on opencv wrapper thing for later look-up! :)

Comment: @Divakar - Ahahah thanks :)  The actual MATLAB module branch is here: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/modules/matlab - The link I gave you before links to the root of the OpenCV source code distribution.  Either way, you'll need to clone the whole repository to get to it.  In the MATLAB module, there is a README on how to get it set up, as well as sample MATLAB calls that show OpenCV working from MATLAB.  On top of this, you can write your own custom MEX functions that call OpenCV and you can call them in MATLAB when you're done.  Thank you for keeping my comments on file :)

Comment: Like many other areas, MATLAB wraps well-known libraries in an easy to use format (think BLAS/LAPACK, FFTW, SparseSuite, just to name a few!). So while MATLAB does make use of OpenCV in its CVST toolbox, it adds many other algorithms not found in OpenCV (either implemented in M-code or a lower-level language). On another note, I can attest to the excellent work done by [Kota Yamaguchi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/798685/kyamagu) in his `mexopencv` project (I contributed myself a few times to the project!).

Comment: Note that the official MATLAB-bindings by Itseez/OpenCV are still in development (expected to be released with the next major OpenCV 3.x version), and many things are not finished yet (the work started as a GSOC project by [Hilton Bristow](https://github.com/hbristow/opencv))

Comment: @Amro - You contributed to `mexopencv`?  I have to kiss your feet then because that library has saved my behind countless times.  Also what you have said has provided very valuable insight.  Thank you again :)  BTW, I recently saw your perceptron post where you drew both ASCII diagrams and provided an animated video.  Just plain awesome.

Comment: @rayryeng: the credit all goes to Kota Yamaguchi for creating an awesome [project](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv), I simply submitted a few pull-requests here and there... Thanks for the kinds words about the perceptron post, you never know what answers get the most votes on Stack Overflow, but pretty pictures do help ;)

Comment: @Amro - Of course, but you contributed so you should get some credit too :)  BTW, I always enjoy your posts... especially the one with entropy and the tree splits.  That's probably my favourite one of all time.